# What if when reading Quran, we don't stop at specified places?

Tags: quran, reading-quran

I enjoy reading Quran, not because it's been commanded to do so, simple because I'm a technical man and I enjoy learning the amount of wisdom presented in this book.
However, there are reading rules, one of which is to stop at specified places.
What if I don't follow those rules? What happens? Is it sin? Does it change the meaning because stops act as semantics for separation of parts?

Comment: Usually the rulings of waqf (or tajweed in general) have a deeper meaning. So refusing to apply them might be both simply wrong as it changes the meaning (more or less crucially depending on the case) or sinful as it may mean that one thinks he could interpret the recitation of the qur'an according his own taste. Nevertheless in general (not specific for the reading of Hafs 'an 'Asim for example) scholars hold the opinion that there's no waqf lazem in the qur'an (no canonical stop), so practicing waqf is always the better choice.

Comment: Rules of tajweed are to be followed no matter what, according to tajweed scholars it is obligatory to follow by tajweed rules, espically when you know them, if not you are sinful.

Answer (score 0):

When you speak English you have full-stop, In Quran you can notice that with Ayah marking. In English you also have comma (,) but in Quran you have these pauses indicated to have more meaning through the tone.

If you dont stop/pause at those places, for a listener who understands it, it may occasionally make less sense to no sense on the statements you are reciting. So right pauses and stops make it more meaningful and more natural for the speaker who speaks from heart as well as the listener who listens with attention.

So following those pauses/breaks is like giving the words of God respect from your heart.